# SignalR falls back to long polling on port 80

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, signalr, signalr-hub

Does anyone have an idea why on a deployment server(Windows 2008 R2 64bit, IIS7.5) SignalR(1.0.0.0 rc1) would fall back to long polling on port 80 but use SSE if the site is configured on a different port?

I don't touch the software - just change the bindings of the site to port 8081 and watch the client logs.

Port 80:

```
    [19:28:15 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate'. jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.min.js:10
[19:28:15 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://192.168.10.91/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionId=0e082fb2-d94d-4907-9579-b4ccde10816d&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22onair%22%7D%5D&tid=8' jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.min.js:10
[19:28:18 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource timed out trying to connect jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.min.js:10
[19:28:18 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource readyState: 0 jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.min.js:10
[19:28:18 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close() jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.min.js:10
[19:28:18 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)] SignalR: This browser supports SSE, skipping Forever Frame. jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.min.js:10
4
Object {Name: "WindowMain", Dock: 2, EleID: "mainContainer", Children: Array[5]}
 jquery.layoutengine.js:52
[19:28:18 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to 'http://192.168.10.91/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&connectionId=0e082fb2-d94d-4907-9579-b4ccde10816d&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22onair%22%7D%5D&tid=8' using longPolling.
```

port 8081

```
[19:28:04 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate'. jquery.signalR-1.0.0-alpha2.min.js:10
[19:28:04 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://192.168.10.91:8081/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionId=08b410ad-7be1-4a94-be02-c713df035c98&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22onair%22%7D%5D&tid=9' jquery.signalR-1.0.0-alpha2.min.js:10
[19:28:04 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource connected jquery.signalR-1.0.0-alpha2.min.js:10
[19:28:04 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 40000 and a connection lost timeout of 60000 jquery.signalR-1.0.0-alpha2.min.js:10
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Are you using classic mode or integrated mode?

Comment: @dfowler - there is no proxy according to the network administrators, the server runs on a virtual machine if that matters. the app pool runs in integrated mode.

Comment: Are you running stuff cross domain?

Comment: @dfowler - I tested this on 2 machine - one in another domain and one which is domain-free - both behave the same.

Comment: I dunno what domain-free means. I'm talking about cross domain with respect to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @dfowler - ah, thought about windows domain(which makes no sense). Then yes - its all in the same domain.